# Arduino with Weighing Scale

Tags: arduino, load-cell, wheatstone-bridge

Let me preface this by saying I'm a total beginner to this. My area is Software, not usually electronics; and I haven't done any since I was in high school.

I've done a lot of reading about Wheatstone bridges in preparation for this, but I'm struggling to apply the diagrams to what I have in front of me.

I'm trying to follow [this](http://www.open-electronics.org/wi-fi-body-scale-with-arduino/) tutorial. In terms of the code side of it, I'm totally fine with what it does, how it calibrates the readings etc. My main problem is the actual scales part of it.

I have the I/O shield that they use in the example as well.

My main problem is the scales. I have a set of scales with 4 load cells in each corner. I have *no* idea where to start with wiring this up. I desoldered the cables from the board, which also handled the power supply, as I figured I would need to rewire a lot of it.

The tutorial itself isn't very clear as it refers to a certain scale, which I can't get in the UK.

Each load cell has 3 cables coming from it: a red, black and white.

[image: Close up of one corner]

My basic questions:

1. How would I go about wiring this into a Wheatstone Bridge?
2. Where would I then connect the battery back to the cables?
3. How can I determine what the individual cables actually do?

If I need to provide any more information, I'll do my best to reply with what you need. Thank you in advance

Comment: Dismantling it further until you find a part number, then look up the datasheet: that ought to give you (3).

Comment: I've had another look at the board. Each cell seems to be grouped into V-, E+, V+ and E-, with each cable taking a position within those groups

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start with this concept: -

[image]

And take your three terminal load cells and fit them at each corner of the diamond like so but note that the labels for input power (+) is in the wrong place unfortunately - basically excitation voltage should be applied across opposite corners and output taken across the two opposite corners remaining: -

[image]

Circuit wise it looks like this: -

[image]

Comment: I assume the "signal+/-" refers to E+/- on the original board?

Comment: I have no idea what your original board is but "E" would imply "excitation" to me corresponding to the DC symbol on my final picture.

Comment: Ah, OK. This is very helpful, thank you. I'll give it a go and see what happens!

Comment: I've made an amendment in a note about the 2nd circuit - it has labels in the wrong place.